# GeoServer property interpolation datastore

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, geoserver-app-schema

I have a problem concerning our GeoServer and implementing a datastore.

Regarding the docs https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/property-interpolation.html
it should be possible the use variables in the definition of a datastore.
I am trying to get a Oracle NG connection to a database using the web-interface.
When inserting normal values for the variables it is working.
When I shutdown the GeoServer and change the parameter database to

`${example.database}` in the datastore and starting it back up it is not working, I just get a null value when trying to add a layer from that datastore in the web-interface. When I look inside the file via web-interface there is still the value `${example.database}`

My App-Schema Properties resides in

```
/data/tomcat/webapps/geodata/WEB-INF/classes/app-schema.properties
```

In the Tomcat startup I defined:

```
-Dapp-schema.properties=/data/tomcat/webapps/geodata/WEB-INF/classes/app-schema.properties
```

inside `app-schema.properties`: `example.database = databasename`

I checked permission for folders and the file itself.

Do I need to create the datastore manually and not the way I am doing it currently via web-interface and then inserting the parameter with an editor?

Is there a problem because my webapp is not named GeoServer?

Or is there something I'm missing like renaming the app-schema.properties or placing it directly in the datastore folder?

This is the datastore.xml:

```
<dataStore>
  <id>DataStoreInfoImpl--78867253:1790e655e57:-7fff</id>
  <name>test_db</name>
  <description>test_db</description>
  <type>Oracle NG</type>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  <workspace>
    <id>WorkspaceInfoImpl--4db88a07:1773e4d4c5e:-7fb8</id>
  </workspace>
  <connectionParameters>
    <entry key="Evictor run periodicity">300</entry>
    <entry key="Estimated extends">true</entry>
    <entry key="Max open prepared statements">50</entry>
    <entry key="fetch size">1000</entry>
    <entry key="Expose primary keys">false</entry>
    <entry key="validate connections">false</entry>
    <entry key="Connection timeout">20</entry>
    <entry key="Batch insert size">1</entry>
    <entry key="Metadata bbox">false</entry>
    <entry key="database">${example.database}</entry>
    <entry key="port">1521</entry>
    <entry key="passwd">the_passwort</entry>
    <entry key="min connections">1</entry>
    <entry key="host">variable from etc/hosts which is working</entry>
    <entry key="Loose bbox">true</entry>
    <entry key="dbtype">oracle</entry>
    <entry key="namespace">http://xxx/geoserver/allgemein</entry>
    <entry key="max connections">10</entry>
    <entry key="Evictor tests per run">3</entry>
    <entry key="Test while idle">true</entry>
    <entry key="user">the_user</entry>
    <entry key="Max connection idle time">300</entry>
  </connectionParameters>
  <__default>false</__default>
  <dateCreated>2021-05-11 07:36:25.152 UTC</dateCreated>
  <dateModified>2021-05-11 07:39:24.759 UTC</dateModified>
</dataStore>
```

The error when trying to create a feature out of this datastore:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also struggling with this same issue where I could not add variables from .properties files inside data_dir configuration files even if app-schema.properties path was set as system variable.

Solution for me was to use environment variables that I could add on runtime environment. For example inside datastore.xml file I could reference environment variable like this:

`<entry key="passwd">${DB_PASSWORD}</entry>`

Geoserver would then replace the template value from environment variable.

**NOTE!** In order this to work Geoserver system variable -DALLOW_ENV_PARAMETRIZATION needs to be set as true.