# GeoServer property interpolation datastore crypt1 password does not work

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, geoserver-app-schema

This is very similar to this question, but not the same.  [GeoServer property interpolation datastore](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396279/geoserver-property-interpolation-datastore)

I'm trying to use ENV variables to populate the values in my datastore using this documentation:  https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/configtemplate.html

So I have a geoserver-environment.properties file in the root of my datadir folder.

```
regulatory.host = ${REGULATORY_HOST}
regulatory.port = ${REGULATORY_PORT}
regulatory.database = ${REGULATORY_DATABASE}
regulatory.schema = ${REGULATORY_SCHEMA}
regulatory.user = ${REGULATORY_USER}
regulatory.passwd = ${REGULATORY_PASSWD}
```

This all works fine except the password (of coarse.. why would it work?).

The variables are set in a docker-compose file and they work fine.  When I echo the values after logging into the container they are set correctly.  The problem is with the password.  In the datastore.xml file the password was formerly saved like the following:
`<entry key="passwd">crypt1:Exxssgsgrrtysaaa....</entry>`

New Entry:
`<entry key="passwd">${regulatory.passwd}</entry>`

I have tried setting my REGULATORY_PASSWD value to a number of things, but it does not work.

```
REGULATORY_PASSWD=crypt1:Exxssgsgrrtysaaa....
REGULATORY_PASSWD=plaintextpassword
```

Also

```
REGULATORY_PASSWD=Exxssgsgrrtysaaa....  AND
<entry key="passwd">crypt1:${regulatory.passwd}</entry>.
```

I keep disabling the account and not having luck having this work.  Now you could ask me why would I want to do this?  You could ask me why use the level one crypt1 method?  Just like the Oracle guys will ask me, why did you lock the account?  Why are you even using Oracle?  Feel free to change the question and turn the guns on me.

I would just like to pass the password and other connection variables into the datastore.xml and have it connect.  When I use the ENV variables for everything else and then modify the datastore.xml using the application, entering the plain text password it connects and works fine.   Like I said it is the password piece that I am stuck on.  It seems to blissfully work for the folks doing the documentation on this page.

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/configtemplate.html

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I can't actually see where they say you can use the password on that page (though neither can I see anything that says you can't)

Comment: I can delete the question or maybe this would be helpful to someone.  I was not able   to enter the passwd parameter using the application.  ${reg.passwd} keyed in gets converted to the above crypt1:xxxyyyzzz format.

Comment: The apply and save button initialize the crypt1 password change.  The only way that I found to get this to work was to vi the datastore.xml file and put in the ${reg.passwd} entry.  The passwd can then be passed in plaintext and it now works.

Comment: Add what you did as an answer and then accept it - that way other people will find it

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use ENV variables to populate the values in my datastore using this documentation: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/configtemplate.html

So I have a geoserver-environment.properties file in the root of my datadir folder.

```
regulatory.host = ${REGULATORY_HOST}
regulatory.port = ${REGULATORY_PORT}
regulatory.database = ${REGULATORY_DATABASE}
regulatory.schema = ${REGULATORY_SCHEMA}
regulatory.user = ${REGULATORY_USER}
regulatory.passwd = ${REGULATORY_PASSWD}
```

When I use the application to modify the datastore all the variables can be setup, except the passwd.  When you enter `${REGULATORY_PASSWD}`, you end up with an encrypted password preceded by crypt1:.

The solution is save the datastore connection with all values, except the password.  Once the datastore is saved locate the correct datastore.xml.

Usually, it is located in `data_dir_location/workspaces/user/datastore.xml`.

edit `datastore.xml` to look like the following:

```
<entry key="passwd">${regulatory.passwd}</entry>.
```